# React is using same component

Tags: reactjs

That's kind weird because I didn't except ReactJS to use same component again and again when I create new dynamic Component!

```
render() {
   let allPopups = this.props.popups;
   let popup;
   if (allPopups.length > 0) {
      popup = <Popup data={allPopups.slice(-1)[0]} close={this.close}/>
   }

    return(<div className="popupManagers">{popup}</div>)
 }
```

Popup Component is reused when render receive new state, the Popup constructor would not run again.

```
class Popup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.first = Math.random(); //let's just say its 0.19760448299684819
  }
}
```

this.first will be "0.19760448299684819" for all popups, where can I find in the react documentation that react will reuse old component that are unmounted? I know for performance this is good, but how can I know this if I did not run into this issue!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the component is unmounted? you can add a key to Popup component to force it to create a new component.

Comment: If I add unique id, the constructor is called every time, I just checked that!

Comment: @JamalJames, could you create a demo fiddle? you can take this as base: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/hLjdt2x4/ (watch the console)

Comment: The sort answer is: it's not supposed to create a new instance of the class. The answer in the question linked above should explain why.

Comment: @JamalJames, I thought you wanna it to be like that?

Comment: React's reconciliation algorithm assumes that without any information to the contrary, if a custom component appears in the same place on subsequent renders, it's the same component as before, so reuses the previous instance rather than creating a new one.